# angle between polynomials

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials, orthonormal

let $v$ be the space of polynomials less than or equal to three and let

> $$\langle p,q\rangle =  p(0)q(0)+p'(0)q'(0)+p(1)q(1)+p'(1)q'(1)$$

What is the angle between the polynomials $2x^3-3x^2$ and $1$?

I was thinking $3\pi/4$ or $4\pi/3$. I was not sure which one it was. I tried drawing a picture and thought it might be $\pi/3$ too. Can someone help me please? I am a self learner and worked on this for days. I came to exhaustion. (real analysis)

Comment: What do you mean by "angle"? I'm guessing that you have an inner product, and you're trying to use the fact that the cosine of the angle is related to the inner product; can you please clarify?

Comment: @T.Bongers yes that is it. sorry about that

Comment: We need an inner product...

Comment: @2929 Can you clearly specify the inner product?

Comment: it is the generization of a dot product. it can be used in vector spaces.

Comment: A typical one for polynomials is $\langle p,q \rangle = k \int_a^b p(t)q(t) dt$. Assuming this is the case, we need $k,a,b$.

Comment: @2929 Yes, that's what an inner product is in general. What is the particular inner product that you are using *in this problem*?

Comment: @2929: He is aware of what an inner product is, he is asking you to specify it (as was I).

Comment: Drawing a picture?

Comment: p(0)q(0)+p'(0)q'(0)+p(1)q(1)+p'(1)q'(1)=<p,q>

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you defined angle. If it is in the standard way we define in vector spaces with inner product. Let $V$ be an $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ vector space with inner product $\langle,\rangle$ the angle $\angle(u,v)$ between vectors $u,v\in V$ is defined by

$$\angle u,v=\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\langle u,v\rangle}{|u||v|}\right)$$

which is well defined because $|\langle u,v\rangle|\leq |u||v|$. In that case, assuming you are dealing with the space of polynomials $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ with the usual inner product we will proceed just computing this thing. Recall that we define

$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^1f(t)g(t)dt,$$

hence, for $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2$ and $g(x)=1$ we have

$$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 2t^3-3t^2dt = -\dfrac{1}{2},$$

$$\langle f,f\rangle =\int_0^1 4t^6-12t^5+9t^4dt = \dfrac{13}{35}\Longrightarrow |f|=\sqrt{13}/\sqrt{35},$$

$$\langle g,g\rangle = \int_0^1 dt=1\Longrightarrow |g|=1.$$

Because of that

$$\angle (f,g)=\cos^{-1}\left(-\sqrt{\dfrac{13}{140}}\right)\approx1,88 \ \text{rad}$$

Comment: +1, but an explicit (and very different) inner product was added recently.

Comment: @T.Bongers can you help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Set $p(x) = 2x^3 - 3x^2$ and $q(x) = 1$. Note that $q'(x) = 0$, so we can compute

$$\langle p, q\rangle = p(0) + p(1) = -1$$

Now we use that

$$\cos\theta = \frac{\langle p, q \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle p, p \rangle \langle q, q \rangle}}$$

Now $\langle q, q\rangle = 2$, and $$\langle p, p\rangle = p(0)^2 + p'(0)^2 + p(1)^2 + p'(1)^2$$

Using the fact that $p'(x) = 6x^2 - 6x$, we see that $p'(0) = p'(1) = 0$, so that

$$\langle p, p\rangle = (-1)^2 = 1$$

Thus $$\cos{\theta} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

The solutions are $\theta = 2n\pi - \frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Comment: would the answer be something like pi/3 in terms of pi?

Comment: @2929 No. The answer would be $2n\pi - 3\pi/4$ for any integer value of $n$ (in particular, $-3\pi/4$ works)

Comment: ahh i see. haha that is what i was thinking in the first place as was my first guess in the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_1(x) = 2x^3-3x^2$, $p_2(x) = 1$. Let $\phi: \mathbb{P}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ be given by $\phi(p) = (p(0), p'(0), p(1), p'(1))$. Then
$\langle p, q \rangle_{\mathbb{P}^3} = \langle \phi(p), \phi(q) \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^4}$, so we see that it is indeed an inner product.

We have $\phi(p_1) = (0,0,-1,0)$, $\phi(p_2) = (1, 0,1,0)$, so we have $\|p_1\|_{\mathbb{P}^3} = 1, \|p_2\|_{\mathbb{P}^3} = \sqrt{2}$, and $\langle p_1, p_2 \rangle_{\mathbb{P}^3} = \langle (0,0,-1,0),  (1,0,1,0) \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^4} = -1$.

The angle is usually defined by $\cos \theta = \frac{\langle p_1, p_2 \rangle_{\mathbb{P}^3}}{\|p_1\|_{\mathbb{P}^3} \|p_2\|_{\mathbb{P}^3}} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Some solutions are $\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: why can it be 3pi/4? why is the answer pi/4 for this question. can you help me see this better.

Comment: T.Bongers got 3pi/4

Comment: @2929: What would $\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}$ be?

Comment: Are you asking why $\cos (\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{4}) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$????